# Flexigrid top margin absolute position

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

How can I get `top margin` of `flexigrid`?

I have multiple tables on page and I need `top margin` for all grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery** `offset()`:

```
$(".flexigrid").offset().top
```

> `1386`

*Tested here: http://flexigrid.info/*